# Can you stockpile resources in your clan castle in clash of clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I understand that when you have completed a war, the resources that you gain from said war will remain in your clan castle until you retrieve them. Do the resources stockpile over a series of successive wars? If not, do the spoils of the latest war trump what was previously in the clan castle?

Answer (score 2):

The spoils do stockpile over the last war you had in succession or in failure, but if someone attacks you they are allowed to take some of the spoils from the clan castle. I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

The money actualy piles up so the awnser to your question is "yes" but, you dont want to do it, there is a very good reason the war screen tels you to collect money because when a clan castle is destroyed, the loot is givven to the attacking player. Therefore there are two things you can do:

1. Defend your clan castle just like your resources.
2. Collect your loot directly after way and dont worry about getting it looted.

It's up to you what you want to do with the "Yes" that I gave you, hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Resources do remain in your castle (now called Treasury even though it's the same building). If you win more loot in war or from Star bonuses *than can fit* in your Treasury it is LOST forever.

Other helpful things to know about the treasury:

1. Your **Spoils of War** accomplishment is not tallied until you collect the loot.
2. If you have more loot than can fit in your storages "Collect" leaves the remainder in the treasury. This is particularly helpful when you want to do research that requires your storage be completely full.
3. Since the January, 2016 update the treasury, like the Town Hall, must be completely destroyed for an attacker to steal the loot.  Storages, however, spill some contents with each hit.
4. The amount of loot that can be stolen from the Treasury is lower than the cap on regular storages.